# How much more efficient is the nuclear fusion reaction of tritium and deuterium compared to two deuterons interacting?

Tags: temperature, nuclear-physics, fusion, scattering-cross-section, nuclear-engineering

Fusion is all the rage (again) these days, and most sources and popular articles claim that tritium-deuterium is the most 'efficient', with a cross-section of about 5 barns....

But what are the cross sections of other reaction types being considered, such as deuterium-deuterium, or ones involving boron, or lithium-6 or lithium-7?

Is there a chart or graph somewhere listing fusion cross-sections?  Hopefully with temperatures required, and maybe costs of materials?

Comment: Consider formatting as a [tag:reference-request]; see the tag wiki for guidelines.

Comment: An old text Controlled Thermonuclear Reactions by Glasstone and Lovberg has some of the information you are looking for. For example, the D-T cross section has a maximum of about 5 barns and the D-D cross section is about 0.03 barns at the deuteron energy 100 kev where the D-T reaction is its maximum .  Other responses can provide more updated information.